# Find value in merged cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem on searching value on a merged cell. Row 9 and Row 10 are merged marked as the grey ones. Now, I want to search a text "TOTAL" and go to its lastrow value which is "2812". Is there a any way to do that without unmerging the cells? Also, the word "TOTAL" is not unique. There's also "TOTAL" on the other 20th column but I want to select the first column who have the word.

[image: The grey filled cells are merged(row 9 and row 10)]

Comment: do a match on the headings column and then do something like cells(lastrow, matchedcolumn).value

Comment: How can I do a match on it if the rows are merged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below assumes headings are in row 1 of the activesheet

```
Sub t()
Dim rng As Range
With ActiveSheet
    Set rng = .Range("A9:" & .Range("ZZ9").End(xlToRight).Address)
    col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("TOTAL", rng, 0)
    lastrow = .Cells(1000000, col).End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print Cells(lastrow, col).Value

End With
End Sub
```

To find a second occurrence, replicate the code and change the start range from "A9" to  .Cells(9, col + 1).Address this will start the new range on the next column

```
Sub t()
Dim rng As Range
With ActiveSheet
    Set rng = .Range("A9:" & .Range("ZZ9").End(xlToRight).Address)
    col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("TOTAL", rng, 0)
    lastrow = .Cells(1000000, col).End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print Cells(lastrow, col).Value

    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(9, col + 1).Address & ":" & .Range("ZZ9").End(xlToRight).Address)
    col2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("TOTAL", rng, 0)
    Debug.Print Cells(lastrow, col + col2).Value

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: are your headings in row 1?

Comment: It's on row 9 and 10. The rows are merged.

Comment: so the headings are merged like A9:B10, 2nd heading A9:B10 etc etc /

Comment: No It's A9:A10, B9:B10 etc.

Comment: made some adjustments to the ranges, try now

Comment: Can you upload an example of your spreadsheet? as this is working here

Comment: Thanks, I've revised your code and It's working now. col = Application.Match("TOTAL", rng, 0) Now, what if I want to select the other row containing "TOTAL"?

Comment: to change the row change Set rng = .Range("A9:" & .Range("ZZ9").End(xlToRight).Address)
to the correct rows you are looking for. e.g. to look at row 10 change "A9" and "ZZ9" to "A10" and "ZZ10" respectivly

Comment: Thanks, what about the other column? The other column who have "TOTAL"?

Comment: I have amended above to find both totals. to find any more you should be able to replicate code as above

Comment: It only selects the 1st column that have the "TOTAL". What if I want to select the next column that has "TOTAL"